# Is there a way to provide a template file (as argument) when opening a new file in vim?

Tags: vim, templates

I have created a command called `vimbin` which is called like this:

```sh
# performs "vim /x/y/z/bin/myscript"
vimbin myscript
```

What I want is that: if the file does not exist, **to provide a default script template to the user when vim opens.**

But I don't want vim to have this behaviour by default. **I want to only have it when called through `vimbin`.**

Is it possible to somehow **provide a template to vim via command-line arguments or environment variable?**

Comment: Replace vimbin by a script does what you want: test if the file exists, if not, copy the template to the new file, start vim with the given filename.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Thank you for the response. In this case if the user does not want to save the file I will be left with a file. I would more preferably like to not write anything under `/x/y/z/bin/` unless the user saves in vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a script vimbin, as follows, and make it executable.

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh

if [ ! -r $1 ]
then
  vim "+0r /usr/local/etc/vimbin_template.txt" $1
else
  vim $1
fi
```

The "ex" command "r" reads a file and inserts it after the current or specified line.  "0r" inserts before the first line.

Comment: `+0r /usr/local/etc/vimbin_template.txt` indeed adds the content as template, which seems to be exactly what I want. Would it be possible that you also provide a reference to vim documentation about this, or explain it?

Comment: No kidding?  It's to be found in "man vim",  "+{command}".  But a lot is lacking, while a couple of decades ago, "man vi" would have taken you days.  Now you need to enter vi/vim, and type ":help".